# Deploying a Guest Executable locally in Azure Service Fabric (Windows 7)

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to deploy a guest executable to a local cluster (Windows 7) but I keep getting errors.  The application listens on two endpoints and they are both defined within the ServiceManifest.xml document.  I am only starting one instance of my application and Service Fabric constantly tears the one instance down and tries to deploy it on another node over and over again.

I created a Service Fabric Cluster in the cloud and I am able to successfully deploy this same executable and hit the endpoints.

I created a Local Fabric Cluster on a Windows 10 machine and I am able to successfully deploy this same executable and hit the endpoints.

**Errors:**

The error I receive associated with the Cluster is "Error event:  SourceId="System.FM", Property="State".  Partition is below target replicat or instance count.

The error I receive associated with each node is:  "Error Event:  SourceId="System.Hosting", Property="CodePackageActivation:Code:EntryPoint".  There was an error during CodePackage activation.  The service host terminated with exit code:3762504530."

Inside the Event Viewer this Error is repeated:
Faulting application name: FabricTypeHost.exe, version: 5.1.150.9590, time stamp: 0x5751635d
Faulting module name: ESE.dll_unloaded, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x524f002d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000540706eb
Faulting process id: 0x3068
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1e1153e9a91c2
Faulting application path: C:\SfDevCluster\Data_Node_2\Fabric\Fabric.Code\FabricTypeHost.exe
Faulting module path: ESE.dll
Report Id: 7c48b2fc-4d08-11e6-befe-64006a967fd4

**The Comment By Andrew at the bottom of the following page** leads me to believe it might be windows 7 specific:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app/

**Solutions** I've tried:

Making sure my application has the proper endpoint bindings that match the URLACLs that Service Fabric specifies (+:Port).

Uploading one of the provided guest executables from github located here: [Simple App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/tree/master/GuestExe/SimpleApplication).  Experienced the same behavior.

I have the latest .NET framework.

Comment: Are both endpoints trying to open the same port?

Comment: No,one is opening 8080 the other is opening 9001, as stated in my question this guest executable runs just fine in the cloud and on a Windows 10 machine.